# How do I randomize items that I got from Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to grab items from the database and show it in a recyclerview in random orders.

**I have tried using Query like this:**

```
Query recipeQuery = mDatabase.startAt("randomLetter");
```

but the problem is that this does not load anything because it does not exactly match the ID of the child in my firebase.

**My data looks like this:**

[image]

As you can see they have different IDs all randomize, and I want to organize it all randomly into a recyclerview. How would I go on about this?

Comment: I don't think it's any more complicated than reading all the children under Recipes, populating a List with them, then shuffling them in memory using Collections.shuffle().  Feed the result to your adapter.

Comment: I actually did not think of that until after I posted the question. I've tried it and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer is actually very simple,

After adding items into the Array List just use

```
Collections.shuffle(recipeList);
```